# What is the lightest cipher that provides AES like security?

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher, stream-cipher, chacha

The lightest, or fastest cipher, that is well known and quite secure like AES. Is ChaCha20 a good option? Are there any better alternatives that are faster but still as secure?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment:

NIST is currently in the process of standardizing a lightweight cipher is intended to provide "AES-like" (i.e., >128-bit) security. However, the evaluation process is still on going and it will still take some years to produce official standards, so it's best not to use any for security critical use cases yet.

Here is a link to the finalists: https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/lightweight-cryptography/finalists

You may also consider the ASCON (also a finalist of the aforementioned LWC competition) or ACORN ciphers for lightweight uses, but again, no standards have been produced here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAESAR_Competition